# Merchants are missing the Resource tab

Tags: pc, horizon-zero-dawn

I am playing on PC Steam.

I have been saving up resources in order to buy the Golden Fast Travel pack so I can fast travel for free.

A quick search shows I need to be beyond the Sacred Lands; I've already reached Meridian.

Then I should be able to find the pack in the Resources tab of any 'Hunting Goods' merchant. However I have visited three merchants, Daytower, one in Meridian and one at the hunting grounds just near Daytower.

None of these merchants even have a Resources tab in the menu. I have made sure I'm in Buy and not Sell.

How do I obtain the Golden Fast Travel pack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that I am just looking in the wrong place. For some reason I was looking at the bottom of the list.

Looking at the merchant again, properly. I can see the Resources tab.

[image: Merchant screen]

Seems I am the bug. [PEBKAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error)